# iOS memory issue

Tags: iphone, ios

I am running an application and we are sometimes receiving the "memory warning", by checking the memory usage, we found that we used about 14MB real memory. But in the mean time in our system there are other applications that used more memory than us(such as 50MB real memory) but they are alive and we got killed.

I am curious how iOS manage the applications and we are afraid if the user's phone is full of other application, our application will be always killed.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but from what I seem, you have higher chances of getting your application killed if you are memory is scaling rapidly. The other application might been scaling slower than yours (memory using/amount of time alive). I am was able to have 80mb of real memory in one application before it was killed. I am guessing there is some kind of mechanism that calculates how fast is the growth of the memory and take the appropriate action.